# Solve the differential equation: $dy/dx=\sqrt y,\ y(0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> I am trying to solve this. But I see that this equation can not satisfy the LIPSCHITZ
>   
>   condition in the interval containing 0.  Can this be solved by separation of variables?

Answer (score 4):

By [Peano existence theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_existence_theorem) the ODE $y^\prime=\sqrt y,\ y(0)=0$ has at least one solution defined in an interval $[0,\alpha)$ with $\alpha >0$. **But**...that solution might not be unique because as you noticed, [Picard-Lindelöf theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) hypothesis are not satisfied.

Hence unicity might not be satisfied...

And indeed it is the case. While you can solve the equation by separation of variables, as mentioned in the other solutions doing so, you're supposing that the solution is not equal to zero in a neighborhood of $0$. **A pretty strong hypothesis as the always vanishing function is also a solution. A good example of an ODE having several solutions!**

$y_1(x)=0$ is a first solution defined on $\mathbb R$. A second one is equal to $y_2(x)=\frac{1}{4}x^2$ for $x \ge 0$.

And as mentioned by [mickep](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/97236/mickep), for $c >0$ the function defined by $\begin{cases}
0 & \text { for } 0 \le x \le c \\
\frac{1}{4} (x-c)^2 & \text{ for } x \ge 0
\end{cases}$ is also a solution.

**Conclusion: the ODE has an infinite number of solutions.**

Comment: And what if $c>0$ and $y(x)=0$ for $0\leq x\leq c$ and $y(x)=\frac{1}{4}(x-c)^2$ for $x>c$(?)...

Comment: Absolutely good remark! The equation has indeed an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: So asuming y not equal to 0. we can apply separation of variable method and get the solution  y =x^2/4. but here we also used y(0)=0.

Comment: But for y(0)=0 we have c=0. so there are 2 solutions.

Comment: Could you comment further on why $c$ isn't $0$? Doesn't the initial value dictate $c=0$ after separation after variables

Comment: @joseph I would revert the question to you... Why do you think that $c = 0$ as the map described in my answer is a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If an equation does not satisfy Lipschitz it still can have a solution. Picard-Lindelöf is not a necessary condition, it is only sufficient.

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{y}$$

$$\frac{dy}{\sqrt{y}}=dx$$
$$y^{-\frac{1}{2}}dy=dx$$

$$\frac{1}{-\frac{1}{2}+1}y^{-\frac{1}{2}+1}=x+c$$

$$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}}y^{\frac{1}{2}}=x+c$$

$$2y^{\frac{1}{2}}=x+c$$
$$y^{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{2}(x+c)$$
$$y=\frac{1}{4}(x+c)^2$$

Now apply IV: $y(x=0)=0=\frac{1}{4}c^2$ or $c=0$.

$$y=\frac{1}{4}x^2$$

Comment: how can u use separation of variable while y(0)=0

Comment: NO there are 2 solutions. Y=0 and Y=X^2/4.

Answer (score 0):

If
$\frac{dy}{dx}
=y^a
$,
$y^{-a}dy = dx
$
or
$\frac{(y^{-a+1})'}{-a+1}
= dx
$.

Integrating,
$\frac{(y^{-a+1})}{-a+1}
= x+c
$,
so
$y 
=((-a+1)(x+c))^{1/(-a+1)}
$.

If
$a = \frac12$,
$y 
= (\frac12(x+c))^{1/(1/2)}
= (\frac12(x+c))^2
= \frac14(x+c)^2
$.

As a check,
$y'
=\frac12(x+c)
=\sqrt{y}
$.